# Redirect to previous url Or back() after login/register in Laravel 5.3

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.3. 
Suppose I am at `(url.com)/posts/5` in a laravel application. Now I want to login. After login I want to redirect back to this url. All I want to edit only these lines in *Auth Controller*. `protected $redirectTo = '/';` as Here says in comment `Where to redirect users after login / registration.`

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
  use AuthenticatesUsers;

  /**
   * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $redirectTo = '/';


  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
  }
}
```

How can I do that? *Note:* I am using laravel built-in authentication.

Answer (score 1):

try with this at RedirectsUsers.php

> edit: I'm new at Laravel but after testing Auth, it redirect back by
>   default.

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

trait RedirectsUsers
{
  /**
   * Get the post register / login redirect path.
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function redirectPath()
  {
    // return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/';
    return redirect()->back();
  }
}
```